# Javascript OOP help/advice/explanation

Tags: javascript, oop, web

Hey all I have a question. I'm writing a small Js Object to make it easier for me to manage what page I'm on in order for me to be able to load proper scripts/styles per page. I am running into a situation that I just dont understand. I have a property `currentPage` that will obviously enough be set to the current page but if I just set it straight from another property I previously defined, it returns a reference error, but if I put it into a function that returns the same thing, it works. I'm not sure why that is. Can someone explain this to me? I'm not a hardcore JS Developer I just figure things out as I go, so is this something specific to JS? Here's a code sample of what I mean :

```
var self = PageInfo = {
    locationArray : window.location.pathname.toString().split("/"),

    printOutPath : function(){
        console.log(self.locationArray.length);
    },
    //ref. error to locationArray
    parentDirectory : self.locationArray[self.locationArray.length -3],
    currentPage : function() {
        return self.locationArray[self.locationArray.length -2]; // works
    } 
};
```

Comment: var self = PageInfo = {}?  Maybe you want to be using this inside the context of PageInfo?

Comment: ouch, defining `self` at line one. Also, are you using `PageInfoObj.parentDirectory` or `PageInfoObj.parentDirectory()` (calling or referencing)?

Comment: I added self just to see if it would get me anywhere. It really didn't. var PageInfo = {} is how I'm going forward with it

Answer (score 4):

When you use JavaScript object literal syntax (creating an object with the curly braces `{}`) the values that go with each property are expressions that get evaluated at the moment the object is created. They can't reference properties of that same object because the object doesn't exist yet.

Note that within your object's methods you can use `this` instead of creating the `self` variable. As long as you call the methods using dot syntax like this:

```
PageInfo.currentPage()
```

...within the method `this` will automatically reference the object so you can do this:

```
var PageInfo = {
    locationArray : window.location.pathname.toString().split("/"),

    printOutPath : function(){
        console.log(this.locationArray.length);
    },

    currentPage : function() { return this.locationArray[this.locationArray.length -2];}
};

alert( PageInfo.currentPage() );
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought It was something along those lines. Would it be any better if I went move along the lines of something like this : `function PageInfo(){
this.locationArray = window.location.pathname.toString().split("/")...
}`

and created the object that way?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "better". If you do that then the properties are created one at a time so you can reference already created ones, but then you'd need to say `var something = new PageInfo();`. A constructor function is definitely appropriate if you need to create multiple instances. Another option is to create most of the properties in the object literal and then add `parentDirectory` afterwards with `self.parentDirectory = self.locationArray[self.locationArray.length -3]; `.

Answer (score 0):

When you define an object, you can't refer to the object until it has been created.  By using a function, you're delaying the lookup of self.locationArray until the object has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Object is assigned to `self` and `PageInfo` only after the execution of the statement. 
So do it after the statement.

```
var self = PageInfo = {
    locationArray : window.location.pathname.toString().split("/"),

    printOutPath : function(){
        console.log(self.locationArray.length);
    },

    currentPage : function() { return self.locationArray[self.locationArray.length -2]; // works
    }
};

self.parentDirectory  =  self.locationArray[self.locationArray.length -3];
```

It will update `PageInfo` also

Use `this` inside functions to make it more OO

```
var self = PageInfo = {
    locationArray : window.location.pathname.toString().split("/"),

    printOutPath : function(){
        console.log(this.locationArray.length);
    },

    currentPage : function() { return this.locationArray[this.locationArray.length -2]; // works
    }
};

self.parentDirectory  =  self.locationArray[self.locationArray.length -3];
```

You can also create a function to set `parentDirectory`

```
var self = PageInfo = {
    locationArray : window.location.pathname.toString().split("/"),

    printOutPath : function(){
        console.log(this.locationArray.length);
    },

    parentDirectory:"",

    setParentDirectory: function() {
         this.parentDirectory  =  this.locationArray[this.locationArray.length -3];  
    },

    currentPage : function() { return this.locationArray[this.locationArray.length -2]; }

};

self.setParentDirectory();
```